# How to find minimum value of each row from a list of specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Here are 4 rows and 4 columns.

```py
a b c d
1 8 2 6
3 6 7 9
1 5 9 4
1 0 6 8
```

I want column 'e' as shown below but below code gives me NaN as output in entire 'e' column.

```py
df["e"]= df.loc[:, ["b", "c", "d"].min()
```

Desired Output

```py
a b c d e
1 8 2 6 1
3 6 7 9 3
1 5 9 4 1
1 0 6 8 0
```

Comment: ``df['e'] = df.min(axis=1)``, missing axis key word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df["e"]= df.loc[:, ["b", "c", "d"]].min(axis = 1)` instead as it has to give the minimum by itering in columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
df['e'] = df.min(axis=1)
```

That'll get your the minimum across all columns, row wise.